# How do I scrape data from this specific website using r?

Tags: r, rvest

I want to download the data from this website.

http://asphaltoilmarket.com/index.php/state-index-tracker/

But the request keeps getting timed out.

I have tried following methods already, but it keep getting timed out.

```
library(rvest)
IndexData <- read_html("http://asphaltoilmarket.com/index.php/state-index-tracker/")
```

```
library(RCurl)
IndexData <- getURL("http://asphaltoilmarket.com/index.php/state-index-tracker/")
```

```
library(httr)
library(XML)
IndexData <- htmlParse(GET(url))
```

This website opens in the browser without any problem, and I am able to download this data using excel and alteryx.

Answer (score 2):

If by "get the data", you mean "scrape the table on that page", then you just need to go a little further.

First thing, you'll want to check the sites `robots.txt` to see if scraping is allowed.  In this case, there is no mention against scraping.

You've got the `html` for the site, you just need to find the css selector for what you want.  You can use developer tools or something like [selector gadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) to find the table and get its css selector.

After that you use the html, extract the node you're interested in with `html_node()` then extract the table with `html_table()`.

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

html <-read_html("http://asphaltoilmarket.com/index.php/state-index-tracker/")

html %>% 
  html_node("#tablepress-5") %>% 
  html_table()
#>             State     Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul
#> 1         Alabama $496.27 $486.86 $482.16 $498.62 $517.44 $529.20 $536.26
#> 2          Alaska $513.33 $513.33 $513.33 $513.33 $513.33 $525.84 $535.00
#> 3         Arizona $476.00 $469.00 $466.00 $463.00 $470.00 $478.00 $480.00
#> 4        Arkansas $503.50 $500.50 $494.00 $503.00 $516.50 $521.20 $525.00
#> 5      California $305.80 $321.00 $346.20 $365.50 $390.10 $380.50 $345.50
#> 6        Colorado $228.10 $301.45 $320.58 $354.12 $348.70 $277.55 $297.23
#> 7     Connecticut $495.00 $495.00 $495.00 $495.00 $502.50 $502.50 $500.56
#> 8        Delaware $493.33 $458.33 $481.67 $496.67 $513.33 $510.00 $498.33
#> 9         Florida $507.30 $484.32 $487.12 $503.38 $518.52 $517.68 $514.03
#> 10        Georgia $515.00 $503.00 $503.00 $517.00 $534.00 $545.00 $550.00
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on robots.txt, and further code for creating the table.  However the "read_html" still does not work for me. For some reason it has something to do with proxy. I got it working by  using `download.file` first and then using `read_html`